# Export ExpandoObject to excel in C#

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

I am using EPPlus to export a list of expanded objects to an Excel file. Initially, I had a single column containing a list of persons separated by ';' (so, the type of object to export was known beforehand), and I was exporting this list within the same column. However, the requirements have changed, and now I need to export each person to a separate Excel cell.

```
Organasation           Adress             Employees

 org1                   Adress             Emp1;Emp2;Emp3...
```

V2 I want it like this

```
Organasation           Adress             Employee1        Employee2       Employee3     ..

 org1                   Adress             Emp1              Emp2              Emp3     ...
```

I tried to export object as expandoObject() as the method expects as input a List